# Массив как поле класса возвращает undefined

Tags: node.js

```
class bin{

    static _array = [];

}
module.exports = bin
```

В другом файле создаю экземпляр класса и обращаюсь к полю _array - console.log(somevariable._array) возвращает undefined, почему?

Comment: Ну так это поле класса, а не экземпляра.

Comment: Как мне это поле объявить, чтоб к нему был доступ?

Comment: Нет, обратиться через имя класса bin._array

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь.